# base class for event receivers in sharepoint 2010 & 2013

Tags: event-receivers, event-handlers, events, remote-event-receiver

What is the name of **Base Class** of event receiver in SP 2010 & 2013?
Are the Base classes same? How to use those?

I have gone through the article on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.speventreceiverbase.aspx) but not clear the things.

Can anyone help me in this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it's same.

SharePoint 2010 Base class URL :

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.speventreceiverbase(v=office.14).aspx

SharePoint 2013 Base class URL :

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.speventreceiverbase.aspx

Please check both URL.

Comment: So
Microsoft.SharePoint.SPEventReceiverBase
this is the base class? OR 
 Microsoft.SharePoint.SPEventReceiverBase
    Microsoft.SharePoint.SPItemEventReceiver
    Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListEventReceiver
    Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWebEventReceiver
    Microsoft.SharePoint.Workflow.SPWorkflowEventReceiver
These all are base classes?

Comment: Microsoft.SharePoint.SPEventReceiverBase- it is base class 
Microsoft.SharePoint.SPItemEventReceiver --- it is base class for Microsoft.SharePoint.SPEventReceiverBase

Comment: Above comment is still confusing! Can you please write it separately?

Comment: Microsoft.SharePoint.SPEventReceiverBase - it is base class of event receiver

Comment: Microsoft.SharePoint.SPItemEventReceiver  - it is base class of Microsoft.SharePoint.SPEventReceiverBase